# Rspec mock validation condition in Validator helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Is there any way of mock these condition checks, without creating a delivery object for each scenario

delivery.blank?

is_delivery_complete?

delivery.phone_number.blank?

delivery.customer_response.try(:service_instance_number).present?

```
module Bss
  module Helper
    module DeliveryValidator

      def validate_action

          return {
              valid: false,
              error_message: "delivery does not have a valid plan"
          } if delivery.blank?
 

           return {
              valid: false,
              error_message: "delivery is not complete"
          } if !is_delivery_complete?
         

           return {
              valid: false,
              error_message: "delivery does not have a mobile number"
          } if delivery.phone_number.blank?
         

           return {
              valid: false,
              error_message: "delivery has customer already created"
          } if delivery.customer_response.try(:service_instance_number).present?
 
        { valid: true }
      end


      def is_delivery_complete?
         !delivery.state_incomplete?
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the RSpec mocks docs? This is a fairly straight forward mocking scenario and I'm not seeing any attempt at actually solving this. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs

Comment: Apart from that I can't see any good reason why you would want to toss 4 vaguely related validations into a single validator. You have 4 different code paths in a single method and that number will likely just grow. A validator should validate one single aspect of the model - not be a junk drawer.

Comment: Yes, it's difficult to mock since the validator has 4 different code paths. maybe this requires some refactor before writing test cases. Thanks for the feedback.
I used FactoryBot seems a good approach to create a service instance that can travel through 4 scenarios, rather than writing query ActiveRecords 

FactoryBot.define do   factory :order do
    delivery_ref "00#{Faker::Number.number(digits: 11)}"
    state 'delivered'
  end
end

Comment: I would start over and write the tests first and then implement one validation at a time in its own validation. All but one of these validations can be done with the built in presence validations if you just use delegation.

Comment: You might want to check out https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers.
It gives you access to great syntax such as `it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }`